# Installing the most recent version of the Z shell

Tags: installation, software-sources, zsh

The [latest release version](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/News/) of zsh is 4.3.14.

I was wondering what is the easiest way to  install it on Ubuntu. Is there a PPA for it? Also, is there a site that lists or collects Ubuntu PPA's for generic packages?

Comment: Don't worry about it and just install (or keep) the `zsh` version on the Ubuntu repository. Most of us can not tell the difference, if any, between one minor version of our favorite shell and another. And yes, I do use `zsh` as my default shell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be interested in `zsh-beta`, it is the Ubuntu repositories (Universe). The advantage is ease of updates. The downside, there may be a bit of a delay (in this case zsh-4.3.14 is not yet in the Ubuntu repositories).

```
sudo apt-get install zsh-beta
```

I did not find any more recent version in any ppa.

The other option is to compile zsh yourself.

Install build-essential

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

[Download](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Arc/source.html) and extract the source code. The documentation in the README and INSTALL is most detailed.

```
cd ~/zsh-3.3.14

# list options
./configure --help 

./configure --prefix=/usr/local

make

sudo make install
```

Your new zsh should be in `/usr/local/bin/zsh`

If it is working, you can add it to `/etc/shells`:

```
command -v zsh | sudo tee -a /etc/shells
```

and then use `chsh` to set your shell:

```
sudo chsh -s "$(command -v zsh)" "${USER}"
```

Log out and log in from your user to see the changes. Typing `echo $SHELL` in your terminal should now yield `/usr/local/bin/zsh`.

Comment: Please notice that you need to install [Yodl](http://www.xs4all.nl/~jantien/yodl/) `sudo apt-get install yodl` **before compiling the sources**. The [documentation tells you about the dependency](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Arc/git.html). - [JuanPablo wrote about the error message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894790/zsh-compilation-problem-in-osx) that you may run into.

Answer (score 3):

There is `zsh` version `4.3.12` available in [jbernard's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jbernard/+ppa-packages) (for Maverick at least).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jbernard/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install zsh
```